# Manually replaying requests queued by workbox-background-sync

Tags: service-worker, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am working on offline support in my PWA app. I am using [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw) for that. This is my current code:

```
const addToFormPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('addToForm');

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
RegExp('MY_PATH'),
  workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
    plugins: [addToFormPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

The code seems to works fine on my computer. However, once I run the app on the phone it takes ages to upload requests stored in IndexedDB. I know that it happens on the SYNC but it seems to take at least 5 minutes. This is not exactly what I need. I wonder if there is an option to access the IndexDB and send all the requests "manually" on click. Another way would be to check if the device is online. Here is how requests are stored:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you **need** to force this, the cleanest approach would be to use the `workbox.backgroundSync.Queue` class (instead of `workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin`) directly.

The `Plugin` class [takes care](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/f2e3165138ee59c9cd18e1a62f5118b0065dc1a5/packages/workbox-background-sync/Plugin.mjs#L41) of setting up a [`fetchDidFail` callback](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins) for you, so if you use the `Queue` class, you need to do that yourself:

```
const queue = new workbox.backgroundSync.Queue('addToForm');

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  RegExp('MY_PATH'),
  workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
    plugins: [{
      fetchDidFail: async ({request}) => {
        await queue.addRequest(request);
      },
    }],
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

You could then call [`queue.replayRequests()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.backgroundSync.Queue#replayRequests) to trigger the replay, e.g., as a result of a `message` event:

```
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data === 'replayRequests') {
    queue.replayRequests();
  }
});
```

But... that all being said, I think your best bet is just to let the browser "do its thing" and figure out when the right time is to replay the queued requests. That will end up being more battery-friendly for mobile devices.

If you're unhappy with the interval that the browser waits before firing a `sync` event, then the best course of action could be to open a bug against the browser—whether it's [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry) (as appears in your screenshot) or another browser.

Comment: how do you implement this into a button on Vue?

Comment: @Kevz you can send message to sw by using the workbox-window:
```
replayRequest() {
  wb.messageSW('replayRequests').then(() => {
     console.log('Background sync queue replayed!');
  });
}
```