# Background sync taking too much time after getting internet connection, workbox

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using service worker to achieve background sync functionality. Following is my code:

```
importScripts(   'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.3/workbox-sw.js' )

const queue = new workbox.backgroundSync.Queue('registerQueue', {   callbacks: {
    queueDidReplay: function(requestArray) {
      let requestSynced = 0
      requestArray.forEach(item => {
        if (!item.error) {
          requestSynced++
        }
      })

      if (requestSynced > 0) {
        new BroadcastChannel('backgroundSynBroadCastChannel').postMessage(
          requestSynced
        )
      }
    }   } }) const GraphQLMatch = /graphql(\S+)?/

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {   if (
    null !== event.request.url.match(GraphQLMatch) &&
    navigator.onLine === false   ) {
    const promiseChain = fetch(event.request.clone()).catch(err => {
      return queue.addRequest(event.request)
    })

    event.waitUntil(promiseChain)   } })

self.addEventListener('message', event => {   if (!event.data) {
    return   }

  switch (event.data) {
    case 'skipWaiting':
      self.skipWaiting()
      break
    default:
      break   } })

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([])

/*  *   Alternate for navigateFallback & navigateFallbackBlacklist  */ workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html', {   blacklist: [/^\/__.*$/] })
```

On internet disconnect, the requests are queued on the indexed DB. But the problem is After acquiring the connection back, the background sync is made at least 5-10 mins later. Is there any way to do the background sync immediately upon internet re-connection or at least reduce the time for syncing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually trigger a replay of a queue as soon as your connection is back by sending an event to the service worker.

In your service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data.type === 'replayQueue') {
    queue.replayRequests();
  }
});
```

In your app *(using workbox-window)*:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) this.wb = new Workbox('/service-worker.js');

window.addEventListener(‘online’, function(event){
     this.wb.messageSW({type: 'replayQueue'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, doesn't look like it's possible right now to change the timing for the sync.  According to [Google's Workbox documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync):

> Browsers that support the BackgroundSync API will automatically replay
>   failed requests on your behalf at an **interval managed by the browser**,
>   likely using **exponential backoff** between replay attempts.

If Google's documentation is correct (at least for Chrome) that also means that the longer the user has been offline, the probability of a longer wait for the sync event increases.

@cyril-hanquez's idea is good as long as the user is still utilizing your site when they come back online.  You might also want to [add a "fetchDidFail" callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992541) to handle more network outage edge cases.  Along those lines:  you might want to avoid relying on the status of "navigator.onLine", since it [doesn't always do what one would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283180).